# Keep only the second and third words of each line in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I **want** **to**...

keep **the** **second**...

and **third** **words** only...

I would like to keep only the second and third words and delete everything else in each line i.e **want** and **to**, **the** and **second**, **third** and **words** and get rid of the rest in each line in notepad++.

Comment: What is a "word" for you? Only alphabetics? Alphanumerics? Word character class `[A-Za-z0-9_]`? Alphanumerics with non latin characters? Everything that is not a space or punctuation? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

#### I would like to keep only the second and third words and delete everything else

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `\w+\s+(\w+)(\s+)(\w+).*`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1\2\3`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

[image]

**Before**:

```
I want to...
keep the second...
and third words only...
```

**After**:

```
want to
the second
third words
```

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Clearly the answer works but it's not explained why it works. Thus, it's only useful to answer this specific question when it could be applied to capturing any number of any specific words on a line.

Comment: @VividKraig That's exactly why I included the Further Reading links.